Angular mat-paginator not working with Parent to Child passing DataSource
I want to use the mat-paginator inside a child component. The mat-paginator should        change the data of a mat-table which is in same child component. Tried available   solutions but not working.
table.component.ts
export class TableComponent<T> implements OnInit  {

MatPaginator(new MatPaginatorIntl(), ChangeDetectorRef.prototype);
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;

@Input()
tableColumns: Array<Column> = [];

@Input()
tableData: Array<T> = [];

displayedColumns: Array<string> = [];

@Input()
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<T> = new MatTableDataSource();

constructor(private cdr : ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.displayedColumns = this.tableColumns.map((c) => c.columnDef);
this.cdr.detectChanges();
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.tableData);
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
}

table.component.html
<mat-paginator [length]="450"  [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20,100]"
            aria-label="Select page of periodic elements"> </mat-paginator>

Parent.component.ts
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Data> = new MatTableDataSource();

constructor(private serviceFetch: ServiceFetch) {}
onClickSearchRmsTradesData() : void {
this.serviceFetch.fetchRecords().subscribe((res : Data[])=>{
this.dataSource= new MatTableDataSource(res);}); } }

parent.html
<app-table [tableColumns]="dataTableColumns" [tableData]="initialData" [dataSource]="dataSource" </app-table>

Tried following provided solutions but not working
Tried with @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator  | any = {}; as well but   not working`
